# Stop receiving notification emails from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

I have searched through the options and settings (and searched for "Facebook email" questions on this website) to no avail.

What I want is very simple: I do not want Facebook to ever send me any notification email again. I'm getting friend request emails, friend confirmation emails, group post notification emails, private message emails...

I think there's a way to block just the group emails from each individual Facebook group, but that doesn't solve my overall problem. I'm being flooded with Facebook update emails, and I just don't want them.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a universal "unsubscribe" setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications&section=through_email&view: select
"*Only notifications about your account, security and privacy*".

Comment: I selected "Only notifications about your account, security and privacy" and I still get an email for every and any activity of everybody on facebook - and no, nothing was hacked!